# Regex to fetch specific data between two *s in between multiple *s

Tags: regex

I have the below Data and want to fetch 101553 from the below data :

This was always after the second * and before the 3rd *.

```
ST*943*0001~
W06*F*101553*20210408*TRLU36543534**FX4564*******~
```

Comment: Best i could do so far is use W06\*.\*(.*?)\* to get the W06*F*101553 value

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=W06\*F\*)(.*?)(?=\*)
```

This worked for me .

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you know that what you want to match is just digits:

```
(?<=W06\*F\*)\d+(?=\*)
```

or, if you don't know what follows the lookahead, you can use a negative character class which allows any chars except `*`:

```
(?<=W06\*F\*)[^*]+(?=\*)
```